# The variants of asking a question

Tags: grammar, questions

"Which topic did you write your article about?"

"About which topic did you write your article?"

"Which topic you wrote your article about?"

Which of these variants would be correct for writing? My take is that the first question is right in every situation, and the second and third are acceptable only in informal speech. I know that the rule says that there is the single correct construction of wh- questions, but I am wondering if there are any other ways of asking a question.

Comment: The first is "natural", the second is "stilted", and the third is syntactic garbage (as a "question" - but it's a perfectly valid "noun phrase" in other contexts). I'm not sure what you mean by *the rule says that there is the single correct construction of wh- questions*, but that doesn't look like any principle of English that I recognise.

Comment: Interesting.  Would you say the same If the preposition 'on' were used?

Comment: @Tuffy Not sure who your comment is addressed to, but please don't try and initiate discussion in comments.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I meant it as a reply to the point Fumble Fingers made.  Obviously I used the wrong 'button. I think that leaving 'on' to the end in a question still jars, whereas 'with' is now perceived as stilted.

Comment: Well, if we're talking about jarring, using _what topic_ instead of just _what_ is pretty jarring. Marks the sentence as a schoolroom exercise instead of native speaker output.

Comment: @Tuffy: I was going to say I couldn't see much difference between ***on*** and ***about*** here. But noting JohnLawler's point, it occurs to me that in almost all likely real-world contexts, there's no reason to explicitly mention "your article" any more than "topic". You'd just say ***What did you write about**?*, and I venture to suggest that just about ***no-one*** would consider using ***on*** instead of ***about*** there (and ***On what did you write**?* is a complete "no-hoper" for the intended meaning).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Absolutely.

Answer (score -1):

Is there anything wrong with simply "What did you write about?" or "What is your article about?" (depending on whether you're more interested in the person or the content).

Comment: You probably shouldn't be phrasing an answer as a question, even if it is rhetorical.